# React Native navigate to another page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im learning React Native. I installed an initial project using `expo init` with the option of tabs.
I've been playing with it but I feel a bit struggled with a simple thing like to create a button and send the user to another page.

All the examples that i can see on google are using a class

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {}
```

and inside the button component:

```
 <Button
      title="Go to Home"
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
    />
```

The thing is that in the example giving when you first create a project, the homeScreen is a function

```
export default function PlayScreen() {
 return (
<View style={styles.container}>
);}
```

My question is how can i make such a simple task? Do you have any examples? Should i change the original code and become it in a class? Do you recommend me to do it?

Thanks

---

Adding the code of the page that i want to change:

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import ListItem from "../components/ListItem";
import { MonoText } from '../components/StyledText';

export default function PlayScreen() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.container}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
        {/* <View style={styles.welcomeContainer}>
          <Image
            source={
              __DEV__
                ? require('../assets/images/robot-dev.png')
                : require('../assets/images/robot-prod.png')
            }
            style={styles.welcomeImage}
          />
        </View> */}
        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingLeft:15, paddingRight: 15,}}>
          <Button title='Search games' style={styles.w80} onPress={HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO REDIRECT THE USER}></Button>
          {/* <Button title='View Map' style={styles.w80} ></Button> */}
          <TabBarIcon
            focused='false'
            onPress=''
            name={
              Platform.OS === 'ios'
                ? `ios-map`
                : 'md-map'
            }
          />
          </View>
        </View>
        <Text style={[styles.header, styles.contentContainer]}>
          Next games:
        </Text>
        <View style={[ styles.w100, styles.pl20, styles.pr20]}>
          {/* <DevelopmentModeNotice /> */}
          <FlatList style={[styles.w100]}
            data={[{key: '1', venue: 'Lammas Park', date: '22/02/2019', startTime: '20:00', endTime: '21:00', maxPlayers: 10, totalPlayers: 9}, {key: '2', venue: 'Lammas Park', date: '22/02/2019', startTime: '21:00', endTime: '22:00', maxPlayers: 12, totalPlayers: 5}]}
            renderItem={({item}) => 

              <ListItem
              image={item.image}
              id={item.key}
              venue={item.venue}
              date={item.date}
              startTime={item.startTime}
              endTime={item.endTime}
              maxPlayer={item.maxPlayer}
              totalPlayer={item.totalPlayer}
              // onItemPressed={() => props.onItemSelected(item.key)}
            />

                // <View style={[styles.contentContainer,  styles.bgGray]}>
                //   <Text>{item.key} - {item.venue}</Text>
                //   <Text>{item.date} - {item.startTime}: {item.endTime}</Text>
                // </View>
            }
          />

        </View>

        <Text style={[styles.header, styles.contentContainer]}>
          Games Completed:
        </Text>
        <View style={[ styles.w100, styles.pl20, styles.mb30]}>
          {/* <DevelopmentModeNotice /> */}
          <FlatList style={styles.w100}
            data={[
              { key: '1', venue: 'Lammas Park', date: '22/02/2019', startTime: '20:00', endTime: '21:00', maxPlayers: 10, totalPlayers: 9}, 
              {key: '2', venue: 'Lammas Park', date: '22/02/2019', startTime: '21:00', endTime: '22:00', maxPlayers: 12, totalPlayers: 5}, 
              {key: '2', venue: 'Lammas Park', date: '22/02/2019', startTime: '21:00', endTime: '22:00', maxPlayers: 12, totalPlayers: 5}, 
              {key: '2', venue: 'Lammas Park', date: '22/02/2019', startTime: '21:00', endTime: '22:00', maxPlayers: 12, totalPlayers: 5}

            ]}
            renderItem={({item}) => 

                <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                  <Text>{item.key} - {item.venue}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.date} - {item.startTime}: {item.endTime}</Text>
                </View>
                  }
          />

        </View>



      </ScrollView>


    </View>
  );
}

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Home',
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    paddingLeft: 20,
  },
  developmentModeText: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 19,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    paddingTop: 30,
  },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, configure the `stack navigator` and move it to the page you left.

**Example**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Details' })
              ],
            }))
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }  
}

class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })
              ],
            }))
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }  
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
  },
  Details: {
    screen: DetailsScreen,
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Comment: Hi Hong
Thanks for your reply. Tried this but come up some errors that require i guess many changes in the original code. Not sure if you are familiar with the code when you run 
> expo init MyProject
and select tabs

I added the original  code on the post

Thanks